# Coaxial Cable Wiring on PCB (WiFi-Card)

Tags: pcb, antenna, reverse-engineering, coaxial

*This post is just serving it's purpose as a discussion in case somone chance upon the same situation as me

I'm really really new to this, so please bear with me.
I got this PCIE wifi card from China, removing the shielding, I realised that they just place a laptop card into a mpcie to pcie adapter. Removing the card, I realised that there are multiple solder point on the pcb for coaxial cables.

[image]

Are the black SMD components on C14, C16 & C18 0 ohm resistors?
( With my limited understanding, those should be 0 ohm resistors, as I can't see the purpose of putting any other components there other than linking the signal connections of the antenna)

Soldering of coaxial cables
If operated properly, the risk of burning through the dielectric shielding should be very low.

I snapped a picture of the wifi card as well, it seems that they got a bunch of intel cards meant for embeded systems and soldered them on to a minipcie generic board:
[image]

Sorry for the poor resolution, but that's the best I could do...

For the card, using a multimeter to conduct a continuity test gives the results of low resistance/short circuit between the outer ring of the ipex 4 connector and the inner pin
(I believe that this isn't normal, as I tested the ipex connector of a working card from realtek and there's no continuity. Then again, do correct me if I could be wrong.)

My 'solutions' are basically ordering a set of biger ipex antennas, removing the existing ipex 4 antennas (can't fit onto my realtek card, which has a bigger ipex connector) and solder the new antennas for other laptops mpcie cards (won't be touching the empty C15 and other points, because I can't really conclude if those are indeed 0 ohm resistors)
And a new set of ipex 4 small connectors for the intel card(some of the comments mentioned that the card could be faulty, to which I agree very much. I just want to rule out the very unlikely possibility that both the ipex 4 connectors were improperly soldered)

I'm really sorry if I messed up the terminologies, I'm by no means a professional...

Comment: Update, the intel card seems weird, the outer right of the ipex and the inner pin is connected, I got another mpcie card from realtek, for this card, the outering of the ipex and the inner pin is not connected. Could it be that the manufacturer messed something up?

Comment: Why such obscure questions about some random product from China? Is there a reason for asking these questions that might motivate someone to dig deep on this?

Comment: Nah, just a random hobbyist hoping to acquire some entry level knowledge on these stuff. PCB designs shouldn't be obscure or is it that I'm asking on the wrong place?

Comment: @LarryLee It's not impossible that the WiFi card was reclaimed from a laptop and could have suffered some damage along the way.

Comment: @LarryLee - Hi, The lack of answers so far could be because: (a) I counted 6 questions, when this site intends there to be 1 per posted question. (b) Your expectations seem unrealistic. You commented: "*PCB designs shouldn't be obscure*". You are asking someone to do reverse-engineering from slightly out-of-focus photos of a PCB with black solder-resist! Some parts of your question are easy, others not. I started to write an answer, but after a while realized the required investment would be more than I can give now. Others might have more time. (c) FYI DMM "continuity beep" =/= short circuit.

Comment: @Andrew Now that I thought about it, this might be the case

Comment: @samgibson Now that I had some sleep, I guess I could simplify my post a bit better now... Thanks for the suggestions